# How to use CMD or ENTRYPOINT with based image that uses ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I am using base image ibmcom/mq which uses `ENTRYPOINT` to execute its process:

`ENTRYPOINT ["mq.sh"]`

If in my `Dockerfile` I use `CMD` the parent image works fine, but my CMD doesn't seem to be executed. If in my `Dockerfile` I use `ENTRYPOINT` my command is running but then the parent `ENTRYPOINT` doesn't seem to be running.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I now understand that if I use CMD it acts as a parameter to the ENTRYPOINT and if I use ENTRYPOINT it overrides it. I thought this is so only within the same Dockerfile.